# How to interact with two mongodb server (mongoose) on one node server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongoose. I have two Mongo DB  Server i.e

> Primary(27017, 27018, 27020 {replica set enabled on primary}) & Secondary(27021)

Now I want to interact with these two server through API in nodejs.  Lets say

```
router.post('/connectToDB1', function (req, res) {
  //Some logic for interacting with DB 1
}) 

router.post('/connectToDB2', function (req, res) {
  //Some logic for interacting with DB 2
})
```

On my node server what I implemented is like this:

```
//On my app.js File

var Mongoose = require('mongoose').Mongoose;
Mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var Message = require('./models/message');
var mydb1;
var mydb2;

var instance1 = new Mongoose();
var uri1 = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017, 127.0.0.1:27018, 127.0.0.1:27020/myDBName?replicaSet=newRep';
instance1.connect(uri1, { useMongoClient: true }).openUri(uri1, function (errr,db) {
    if (errr) {
        throw errr;
    } else {
        console.log("Primary Connection Successfull");      
        mydb1 = instance1;
    }
});

var instance2 = new Mongoose();
var uri2 = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27021/secondary';
instance2.connect(uri2, { useMongoClient: true }).openUri(uri2 , function (errr,db) {
    if (errr) {
        throw errr;
    } else {
        console.log("Secondary Connection Successfull");      
        mydb2 = instance2;
    }
});
```

Now I don't Know how to Interact/create A Query...

Any help is really Apreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Mongoose has a function called [createConnection()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-createConnection) that returns a connection object. You can create multiple connections to different servers/replicaSets and create models specific to each connection. Here is an example:

**49790706.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const conn1 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/test1');
const conn2 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27018/test2');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

const adminSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

const User = conn1.model('User', userSchema);
const Admin = conn2.model('Admin', adminSchema);

const billy = new User({ name: 'Billy' });
const root = new Admin({ name: 'root' });

async function run () {
  await conn1.dropDatabase();
  await conn2.dropDatabase();
  await billy.save();
  await root.save();
  let b = await User.find({});
  let r = await Admin.find({});
  console.log('users:', b);
  console.log('admins:', r);
  return mongoose.disconnect();
}

run();
```

**shell output**

```
stack: ./49790706.js
users: [ { _id: 5acf1b72bb7d5f546c1a526f, name: 'Billy', __v: 0 } ]
admins: [ { _id: 5acf1b72bb7d5f546c1a5270, name: 'root', __v: 0 } ]
stack:
```

You need to be sure that when you create your models you attach them to the specific relevant connection, ie `conn1.model(..)`. Also, when your app is ready to close the connections rather than call `.close()` on each one, note that you can call `mongoose.disconnect()` and it will close all connections in parallel.

Comment: See I have a seperate directory for Models. All DB Models Will be saved there. Like this : "var Message = require('./models/message');" Now after creating the Two Connection How I can Interact With the specific Db Query. And What are the Scenerio when Both Db Have same collection. It means there name is also same. then How can i figureout that request is created for which server

Comment: instead of exporting the Model's from modules, you can export the schema from modules and create the connections in one place, or you can create the connections in each separate module, attach the models as in my answer above, and export the connection object instead. My example has a separate query for each DB, one is performed on the User Model, the other on the Admin Model ( each Model is on a different database ). Both collections can have the same name, they're on different databases after all. You just have to be careful when you name the javascript variable for each one.